# sign-up:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, html, django

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RfRV.png)

I get Internal Server Error (500) on the Django sign-up page. How can I fix the *is_ajax* attribute issue?

Description:

I'm currently working on a Django project and have run into an Internal Server Error (500) on the sign-up page. After some investigation, it appears to be related to the *is_ajax* attribute in the *views.py* file. I've included the relevant code snippets and traceback below for your review.

#### File *views.py*

```
class SignUpView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-up with reCAPTCHA security
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_up.html"
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = "/"

    # reCAPTURE key required in context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["recaptcha_site_key"] = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
        return context

    # Overwrite the mixin logic to get, check and save reCAPTURE score
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()

                login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                # Change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"

            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)

        return response
```

#### File *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AccountView.as_view(), name="account"),
    path('profile', views.profile_view, name="profile"),
    path('sign-up', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="sign-up"),
    path('sign-in', views.SignInView.as_view(), name="sign-in"),
    path('sign-out', views.sign_out, name="sign-out"),
]
```

#### File *sign_up.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block extend_head %}
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{recaptcha_site_key}}'></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Django Google API Course - Sign Up</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form id="signupform" method="POST" action="/sign-up">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    {{form.first_name}}

    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    {{form.last_name}}

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    {{form.username}}

    <label for="password1">Password</label>
    {{form.password1}}

    <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
    {{form.password2}}

    {{form.token}}

    <label class="check-container">Show Passwords
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="showPword()">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extend_footer %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Create a variable that can be used in main.js
  var recaptcha_site_key = '{{recaptcha_site_key|safe}}'
</script>
{% endblock %}


base.html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.css" integrity="sha512-3pIirOrwegjM6erE5gPSwkUzO+3cTjpnV9lexlNZqvupR64iZBnOOTiiLPb9M36zpMScbmUNIcHUqKD47M719g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  {% block extend_head %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% include 'partials/nav.html' %}
  <div class="div-container">
    {% include 'partials/logo.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js" integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  {% block extend_footer %}
  {% endblock %}
  <script src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add error message instead of image

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77467731/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Your issue with the Internal Server Error (500) on the sign-up page seems to be related to the use of the is_ajax() method in Django. Starting with Django 3.1, is_ajax() is deprecated, and using it can lead to unexpected errors. Here’s how you can resolve this issue:

#### Replacing is_ajax()

Replace the is_ajax() method with a custom implementation. You can define a function to check if the request is an AJAX call:

```py
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Then, use this function in your **`SignUpView`** class:

```py
# ... other parts of your class ...

def form_valid(self, form):
    response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
    if is_ajax(self.request):  # Use the custom is_ajax function
        # ... rest of your code ...
```

#### Why this issue might have arisen

The is_ajax() method was a convenient way to check if the request is an AJAX call. However, it was deprecated because the XMLHttpRequest object, which is used to make AJAX calls, is slowly being replaced by the fetch API in modern web development. Django decided to remove this method to encourage developers to use more up-to-date techniques and because the value of the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header, which is_ajax() checks, can be easily spoofed, making it unreliable for security-sensitive operations.

### Additional Recommendations

Check Django Version: Ensure your project is compatible with the version of Django you are using, especially if it’s 3.1 or later.

Server Logs: Look into your server logs for more specific error details if the issue persists after this change.

Form and AJAX Request Handling: Verify that your form is correctly set up and that AJAX requests are properly formatted and handled.

- **NOTE**: it is advisable to turn the `DEBUG`=True when we are trying to get more insights to a question.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?

Comment: Ohh no it was not